# MySQL Select based on max of multiple columns

Tags: mysql

Say I have this table called `Record`

```
| user_id | work.id | trans.id |
|   1     |   1     |    1     |
|   1     |   2     |    1     |
|   1     |   3     |    2     |
|   2     |   4     |    3     |
|   2     |   5     |    3     |
|   3     |   6     |    4     |
|   3     |   7     |    5     |
```

How can I get a result based on the maximum of `work.id` and `trans.id` **grouped** by `user_id`?

```
| user_id | work.id | trans.id |
|   1     |   3     |    2     |
|   2     |   5     |    3     |
|   3     |   7     |    5     |
```

Any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: Max with group by

Comment: [tutorial on max with group by](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-max-with-group-by.php)

Answer (score 1):

You need basic grouping with max():

```
 Select userid , max(workid), max(transid)   from    Record group by userid;
```